# failing to install kivy in ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-19ocdenh/kivy/
```

is the error code I get when I try to install kivy on a virtual env or globally on my machine. What does it mean? How do I resolve this? Other packages like django, numpy all went nicely, but, kivy doesn't. I've checked and marked all the dependencies listed on the main installation site, including stuff like Cython, but It does't budge.

Comment: I have installed Kivy globally or in a virtualenv on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the instructions from [Installation in a Virtual Environment](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#ubuntu-11-10-or-newer)

Comment: @ikolim , not working for me.

Comment: @mathmaniage could you please update the question with your Kivy installation process?  That would be really helpful.

Comment: @realslimshanky , I still haven't installed it on a virtualenv, but, sudo apt install kivy did it I think. Sorry, I've forgotten about this issue because, I made my project on kivy, but unsuccessful to build it on android. It's really painful....